# How to save canvas on Right-Click dialog as jpg

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, export, jpeg

I'm using this code to capture images as canvas from a video `URL` in my site:

```
var videoId = 'video';
var scaleFactor = 0.55; // increase or decrease size
var snapshots = []; 
/**
 * Captures a image frame from the provided video element.
 *
 * @param {Video} video HTML5 video element from where the image frame will be captured.
 * @param {Number} scaleFactor Factor to scale the canvas element that will be return. This is an optional parameter.
 *
 * @return {Canvas}
 */

function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
    if(scaleFactor == null){
        scaleFactor = 1;
    }

    var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
    var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = w;
        canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
    var uniq = 'img_' + (new Date()).getTime();
    canvas.setAttribute('id', uniq);

  return canvas ;

}

/**
 * Invokes the <code>capture</code> function and attaches the canvas element to the DOM.
 */
function shoot(){
    var video  = document.getElementById(videoId);
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);

    snapshots.unshift(canvas);
    output.innerHTML = '' ;

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
       output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);

    }
}
```

**My two problems:**

1 - Currently, browsers treat `<canvas>` like they they treat a `<div>` and this make it impossible to save any generated canvas as an image because when I `right-click` on each and everyone, it always opens the windows dialog here I have to choose `Save image as...`.

2 - The windows `right-click` dialog always opens by default the option to save image as `transfer.png` and I would like to save the image with their `ID attribute` (`var uniq`) and a `jpg` extension.

**Example of what I need:**

The output canvas is like this: `<canvas width="352" height="198" id="img_1575807516362"></canvas>`.

I want the `right-click` to open the windows dialog offering to save image like this `img_1575807516362.jpg`.

Alternatively, it would be nice tho have a download button for each canvas to export the `canvas` as an image like this `transfer.jpg`.

Is it possible to  make this work with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance. It took me some time, but I wanted to make sure that I got it working properly. I am not sure if there is a way to do a windows dialog to save to file (Where it pulls up the save as... prompt), but you can definitely create a download button to do this.

**Downloading the Image**

First, we need to create a download button:

```html
<button onmousedown="download()">Download</button>
```

Second, we can create a function to download the image with a key. 
The easiest way to do this is creating a downloadable `<a>` tag:

```js
var download = function(){
    var link = document.createElement('a'); //Creates an 'a' element
    var thisCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]; //gets the first canvas element on the page, assuming the canvas you want to download is this element. 
    link.download = `${thisCanvas.id}.jpeg`; //Gives the download an output link
    link.href = thisCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") //Gives the data to the link
    link.click(); //Clicks the 'a' element we created
    }
```

If you wanted to ask for user input whether or not they want to download, you can use:

```js
var download = function() {
    if (window.confirm("Would you like to download this frame?")) { 
        var link = document.createElement('a'); //Creates an 'a' element
        var thisCanvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]; //Gets the canvas
        link.download = `${thisCanvas.id}.jpeg`; //Gives the download an output link
        link.href = thisCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") //Gives the data to the link
        link.click(); //Clicks the 'a' element we created
    }
}
```

You can always change the name of the image file as well with `link.download = imageName + ".jpeg"`

**Creating A Button in JS**

EDIT: If you want to create the button in javascript instead of html, you can do the following:

```js
var createbutton = function() {
    var b = document.createElement('button'); //Creates the button
    b.onmousedown = function() { //Creates an onmousedown event for the button
        download(); //This is the download function above
    }
    b.innerHTML = "Download"; //Gives the button Text
    //Here, you can insert button styles using: b.style 
    document.body.appendChild(b); //Appends the button to the body
}
```

You can call this function whenever you need to create the download button. This function creates a button at the end of the body, but you can change the location:

```js
   //Where it says document.body.appendChild(b); , replace it with:
   document.getElementById(`myCustomId`).appendChild(b);
   //This places the button in any element on the page with 'myCustomId'
```

**Canvas onmousedown events, and downloading all images**

EDIT (2):

If you have multiple canvases that are created within `snapshots`, then you can do the following to download **all** the snapshots:

```js
var download = function(){
    var link = document.createElement('a'); //Creates an 'a' element
    snapshots.forEach(snap => {
        link.download = `${snap.id}.jpeg`; //Gives the download an output link
        link.href = snap.toDataURL("image/jpeg") //Gives the data to the link
        link.click(); //Clicks the 'a' element we created
    });

    }
```

If you want to download one image at a time, you can give them an onmousedown event when you add them. Let's edit the download function to support this:

```js
var download = function(canvas){
    var link = document.createElement('a'); //Creates an 'a' element
    link.download = `${canvas.id}.jpeg`; //Gives the download an output link
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") //Gives the data to the link
    link.click(); //Clicks the 'a' element we created
}

//We also need to edit the shoot() function

function shoot(){
    var video  = document.getElementById(videoId);
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);
    canvas.onmousedown = function() {
        download(canvas);
    }

    snapshots.unshift(canvas);
    output.innerHTML = '' ;

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
       output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);

    }
}
```

This way whenever you append all of the snapshots, each canvas comes with it's own mousedown event, so clicking on it will return the image. You can even add a confirm box or check if right mouse is clicked here.

**Question 2**: It doesn't matter where the functions go, only where you call them.

If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: Two things... **Firstly**: My code generates several images/frames and I need to choose the one I need to download (one download button per picture/frame). Your code gets only the first canvas element on the page. 
 **Secondly**: Where (in my code) should I paste your functions/snippets?

Comment: OK! I've pasted the `var download = function(canvas)` function (**not the download all version**) above the "shoot()" function like stated on your example. Then, I changed the **shoot** function by pasting the `canvas.onmousedown...` like you said. After that, I've pasted the `var createbutton = function() {` bellow the`var download = function(canvas)` function, commented the line `document.body.appendChild(b);` and called this way  `output.appendChild(createbutton);` bellow the `output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);` of the **shoot** function but nothing happens... Where did I go wrong?

Comment: let me try and fully create the script you are trying to do. I will paste the code I get soon to a jsfiddle.

Comment: I am still trying to work out the bugs. For some reason ```canvas.toDataURL``` is not wanting to trigger on a ```onmousedown``` or ```onclick``` event. Usually, the method to do so would be using ```canvas.toDataURL``` and then download it, however it doesn't want to work. I will keep working on this.

Comment: Hi @Malmadork , any news on this?